# Changing custom cell's height dynamically not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, height

I want to set the height of a cell dynamically based on a label's height.

I created the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ORDStepsCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

UILabel *stepsLabel;
UILabel *stepsNumberLabel;
UIImageView *bulletImageView;
UIImageView *cellBackgroungImage;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    CGRect stepsLabelFrame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 253, 21);
    CGRect bulletImageViewFrame = CGRectMake(281, 25, 29, 29);;
    CGRect stepsNumberLabelFrame = CGRectMake(3, 3, 21, 21);
    CGRect cellBackgroungImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);

    cellBackgroungImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cellBackgroungImageFrame];
    cellBackgroungImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list-item"];

    stepsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:stepsLabelFrame];
    stepsLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    stepsLabel.tag = 0;

    bulletImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bulletImageViewFrame];
    bulletImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"step-bullet"];

    stepsNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:stepsNumberLabelFrame];
    stepsNumberLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    stepsNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    stepsNumberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    stepsNumberLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    stepsNumberLabel.tag = 1;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellBackgroungImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:stepsLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:bulletImageView];
    [bulletImageView addSubview:stepsNumberLabel];

} else {
    stepsLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
    stepsNumberLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
}

stepsLabel.text = [preperationSteps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[stepsLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[stepsLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[stepsLabel sizeToFit];

NSLog(@"cellHeight = %f", cell.frame.size.height);

stepsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, (cell.frame.size.height - stepsLabel.frame.size.height) / 2, 253, stepsLabel.frame.size.height);

stepsNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row + 1];

[cell setSelected:NO];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];

return cell;

}
```

Then I calculated the label's height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 253, 30)];
NSString *labelText = [preperationSteps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cellLabel.text = labelText;
[cellLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

[cellLabel sizeToFit];

cellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 253, cellLabel.frame.size.height);
CGFloat cellLabelHeight = cellLabel.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"cellLabelHeight = %f", cellLabelHeight + 20);
return cellLabelHeight + 20;
}
```

In the log:

```
2013-03-08 17:37:18.161 Recipe[37547:c07] cellLabelHeight = 125.000000
2013-03-08 17:37:18.161 Recipe[37547:c07] cellLabelHeight = 62.000000
2013-03-08 17:37:18.161 Recipe[37547:c07] cellLabelHeight = 41.000000
2013-03-08 17:37:18.162 Recipe[37547:c07] cellLabelHeight = 41.000000
2013-03-08 17:37:18.162 Recipe[37547:c07] cellLabelHeight = 41.000000
2013-03-08 17:37:18.162 Recipe[37547:c07] cellLabelHeight = 41.000000
2013-03-08 17:37:18.163 Recipe[37547:c07] cellLabelHeight = 62.000000
2013-03-08 17:39:34.852 Recipe[37581:c07] cellHeight = 44.000000
2013-03-08 17:39:34.852 Recipe[37581:c07] cellHeight = 44.000000
2013-03-08 17:39:34.853 Recipe[37581:c07] cellHeight = 44.000000
2013-03-08 17:39:34.853 Recipe[37581:c07] cellHeight = 44.000000
2013-03-08 17:39:34.854 Recipe[37581:c07] cellHeight = 44.000000
2013-03-08 17:39:34.854 Recipe[37581:c07] cellHeight = 44.000000
2013-03-08 17:39:34.855 Recipe[37581:c07] cellHeight = 44.000000
```

As you can see the cell's height is fixed 44 even though the value returned from heightForRowAtIndexPath is different.
I know that heightForRowAtIndexPath is called before cellForRowAtIndexPath (as can be seen in the log), so how can I change the height?

Comment: The cell's height is not set in the call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. That method simply returns a cell with a standard height. Once the table gets the cell and adds it to the table, the cell's height will be set. So logging the height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is misleading. Just make sure your cell's custom content properly adjusts itself when the cell's height is eventually set to the full height.

Comment: If you use the following, what happens? - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { return [indexPath row]; }

Comment: I can see one cell and separators inside it.

Comment: I am only saying if the row does not gradually increases with the code above, then he has a problem somewhere else.  That's why I said 'what happens?'

Comment: Where do I need to adjust the cell's subviews if the height in cellForRowAtIndexPath is the default one? In willDisplayCell?

Comment: It's no different than ensuring subviews properly size themselves with any other view. Use proper `autoresizingMasks`, use constraints, or define a custom cell class and use `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: All right.  Sorry about that...

Answer (score 1):

The height that you are giving in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is what is getting displayed. Paste this code in your controller and see what height you are actually displaying.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%f", cell.frame.size.height);
}
```

The height that you are logging in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is just a default height for the cell. The height gets assigned after the the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called.

Comment: It does show the correct height. The first cell is showing correctly (except for the background which I tried to set with stretchable image) but the other cells get on top of each other which hiding the label. So where do I need to calculate the label's frame if the cell's height in cellForRowAtIndexPath is not the desired one?

Comment: From what I can see in your code, you have hardcoded the height for the background image to 80. Since height of your background imageview depends on the height of the cell, you must use the height of the cell that you have calculated to avoid the overlapping. You might also use the `willDisplayCell` method to access the cell's variable height for your imageView's frame calculation.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set the height of a cell dynamically based on a label's height.

You might want that, but you're not setting the cell height anywhere in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. The `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` doesn't set the height of the cell for you -- you need to do that when you configure the cell in the former method. The reason for the latter method is so that the table can determine what its own height is. Whenever it reloads its data, it asks the delegate for the height of every row, and it uses that information to calculate the total height of the table. You still have to set the cell height every time you provide a cell for a given row.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem for me is calculate the label's text length using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`  in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` methods and then set the frame for the label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` using the size that was calculated.
If it will be of any help to anyone I will post the code.